# Angular ui-router dynamic params double slash

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have ui-router's config like below:

```
.state('xxx.components',{
            url: '/:runId/component',
            reloadOnSearch: false,
            templateUrl: '/modules/xxx//views/cloud-components/templates/cloud-components.tpl.html',
            controller: 'CloudComponentsCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        })
```

if i go to the component page without any runId, the url will look like below:

```
http://localhost:3031/xxx/run-topologies//component
```

It will contain double slash in the url, i want it only contains one slash like below, what should i do can solve this issue?

expect behavior:

**with runId:** (This is correct due to current config)

```
http://localhost:3031/xxx/run-topologies/6/component
```

**without runId:** (should be only 1 slash)

```
http://localhost:3031/xxx/run-topologies/component
```

Comment: Would the SPA have a different behavior when there's no ID? if so, you should use two different states as Lizzie suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible AFAIK. But, there are two ways that you might be interested in which will use the `CloudComponentsCtrl` for both routes.

1. Define a separate state with a url without runId

   ```
   .state('xxx.components',{
       url: '/component',
       reloadOnSearch: false,
       templateUrl: '/modules/xxx/views/cloud-components/templates/cloud-components.tpl.html',
       controller: 'CloudComponentsCtrl',
       controllerAs: 'ctrl'
   })
   .state('xxx.componentsForRunId',{
       url: '/:runId/component',
       reloadOnSearch: false,
       templateUrl: '/modules/xxx/views/cloud-components/templates/cloud-components.tpl.html',
       controller: 'CloudComponentsCtrl',
       controllerAs: 'ctrl'
   })
   ```
2. Remove runId from the route and include it as a query parameter.

   ```
   .state('xxx.components',{
       url: '/component?runId',
       reloadOnSearch: false,
       templateUrl: '/modules/xxx/views/cloud-components/templates/cloud-components.tpl.html',
       controller: 'CloudComponentsCtrl',
       controllerAs: 'ctrl'
   })
   ```

   Then you can access runId in from your `$stateParams`.

Hope this addresses your problem in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will go with your answer#2. Since my real case is more complex than this example, and i also tried using answer#1, it seems i still got lots of things to fix. Answer#2 is perfect!